# How to use dataview to check same Value

Tags: c#, sql, dataview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
res.Fill(dt);
```

it is get sql data code.

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = tt_id;
dr[1] = fault_desc;
dr[2] = tt_time;

dt.Rows.Add(dr);

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

Response.Write(dv);

if (dv.Count != dv.ToTable(true, "tt_id").Rows.Count) {
  // string sqlstr = string.Format("insert 
}
```

I want to use dataview to check the new data which have existed in sql before
if exist cancel to insert.
the problems is the response said that I have same value 
but I check it where didn't have any same value in dv.
what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var duplicateValues = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   orderby row.Field<string>("Id")
                   select new DuplicateObject
                   {
                       Id = row.Field<string>("Id"),
                       Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
                       Skill = row.Field<string>("Skill")
                   }).Distinct(new DuplicateObjectComparer()).ToList();

string dupValue = string.Empty;

foreach (var dup in duplicateValues)
{
dupValue = dup.Id + " - " + dup.Name + " - " + dup.Skill;
Console.WriteLine("Duplicate entry:" + dupValue);
}

if (duplicateValues.Count == 0)
Console.WriteLine("No duplicate entry");
// Supporting classes
// Gives a strongly type class from the Linq query    
public class DuplicateObject
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Skill { get; set; }
}
```